# Accessing userscript variables from the Google Chrome console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console, userscripts

For debugging purposes, is it possible to access userscript variables from the console in Google Chrome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you had a Chrome userscript with this code:

```
var userscriptVar = "I'm a global variable, userscript context.";
window.var2       = "I'm a window.scope variable, userscript context.";

console.log ("Hello from the userscript.");
```

To access these userscript variables:

1. Determine the userscript's ID.  You can see it on the extensions page (`chrome://extensions/`):

   [image: Getting script's ID]
2. Switch to the script's context by clicking on the context menu at the bottom of the console:

   [image: Switch to userscript scope]

   Note that the id (`pfnbaeafniclcjhfkndoploalomdmgkc`) is the same as that listed on the extensions page.
3. Now you will immediately be able to see and change the window-scoped variable (`var2`), but you can't see the userscript's global (`userscriptVar`) because the script-instance has long since finished and disappeared. :

   [image: Accessing Script vars after script is done]
4. To access and change userscript variables, while the script is still active, set a breakpoint in the script and use the debugger.  See [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13577880/331508) for how to do that.

   [(Click for a larger image)

   [image: Userscript paused at a breakpoint]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAwxh.gif)
5. With the userscript paused at a suitable breakpoint, you can see, but not change the global values, from the console.

   [(Click for a larger image)

   [image: Can't change from console]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OwVZ.gif)
6. But you can change the value from the debugger:

   [(Click for a larger image)

   [image: Setting the value]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZGX9.gif)

Comment: Changed my answer because this is so detailed a 5yo could understand ;-)

Answer (score 1):

hum yes. Just type the var name and hit enter to evaluate (use `dir(xxx)` for objects)

NB: var must be <s>global</s>set on `unsafeWindow`

Comment: Does not work. Probably because each userscript is embeded in annonymous function.

Comment: I think you are trying to access local var, try logging instead with `console.log(var)`

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is I made the variable global. i.e

```
var x = "Chairman Mao";  // x not accessible to chrome
    x = "Chairman Mao";  // X becomes accessible to chrome via inspector
```